# Nginx rewrite url to url and title

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to do is to rewrite with nginx

```
 http://example.com/ID/xxx

 to 

 http://example.com/ID/xxx/title-of-the-article
```

I have a idea that this is best done with rewrite rules
but maybe it can be done only with PHP script?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply redirect the user from the above URL to the one below?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it gives better SEO ranking and easier to read.

Comment: Redirects are not necessarily bad for SEO, it seems (according to http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection). Doing a 301 redirect would be simpler than either dynamically resolving the title inside nginx or modifying its config when each new post is added.